# Collection fetch and model parse

Tags: backbone.js

I override function parse() in my model, when name or surname from the database is empty I'm asking Facebook API for that:

```
var Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
parse : function(response) {
    var self = response,
        that = this;

    if(!response.first_name) {
        FB.api('/'+response.fbid, function(response) { 
            self.first_name = response.first_name;
            self.surname = response.last_name;
        });
    }

    return self;
}
});
```

My problem is that during fetch-ing in collection this values (first_name and surname) are still empty (though console.log in the model shows it properly). How could I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript call to `FB.api` is async, so basically there is no delay between `FB.api` and `return self`. Since your `console.log(model)` is probably immediately after fetch there is no returned data from `FB.api` since the request is not over.

What you could do is set try to put some callback when your model is updated and listen to it, and if you change the model trigger `update` method something like ...

```
Friend.fetch( { success: function(model, response) { 
    if ( !model.get('first_name') ) {
        FB.api('/'+model.get('fbid'), function(fb_response) {
            model.set('first_name', fb_response.first_name);
            model.set('last_name', fb_response.last_name);
            console.log('model updated with facbook info', model);
        });
    }
}});
```

Try running ( in your current code ) `console.log('updated');` in your `FB.api` callback to see the delay I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks, I did it as you said, triggering an event where model is updated.